# What are my basement walls poured concrete or cinder block? (Pics inside)

Tags: concrete, walls, basement, plaster, cinderblock

Trying to figure out what kind of basement walls I have. Vertical seams are visible and corners are rounded.

Poured concrete? Cinder block? Something else?
[image: wall with vertical seams]

[image: rounded corners]

Comment: They appear to be poured concrete.  Why do you need to know?

Comment: Almost assuredly poured concrete, especially with the way it's formed in the window area.  Block walls wouldn't have a window framed like that.

Comment: The rounded corners are another sign.  They are easier to do with concrete, but could be done with rounded blocks.  Most signs seem to point to concrete, but it is possible blocks with heavy parging.  The finish suggests concrete with rough forming boards.

Comment: @RMDman thanks, just preparing to rennovate my basement and the rounded corners piqued my interest

Comment: @Milwrdfan good to know! luckily i got the window in the shot because that wasn't my intention

Comment: @crip659 i appreciate the detailed answer